# Can I debug libraries (DLLs) directly using CLion?

Tags: debugging, dll, clion

I'm using CLion IDE to work on multiple CMake projects which have libraries as output target (in my special case DLLs as I'm on Windows). Now it would be extremely handy to directly Debug/Run certain methods, using e.g. using CLion's Configurations. Is this possible? If not, what's the best way to debug such libraries?

Comment: I never used CLion. But in visual studio: 1. write an exe (ex. a.exe) which invoke this dll (b.dll), 2. generate a.exe in the same folder of the b.dll 3. in the debug configuration of dll project, write the path of a.exe 4. debug

Comment: Thanks, @neohope, this is more or less the way I'm working now. Given there won't turn up a better solution during the next days, I'd accept this as answer.