# Clion - Can I debug across projects?

Tags: c++, clion

I have the following setup for my C++ application:

1. Project "Common" with 6 cpp source files. One of these cpp sources is named `dataclasses.cpp`. The output of this project is `libgeneral.dylib`, to be used in the next project below.
2. Project "Algorithm" with only one cpp source file. This project uses the `libgeneral.dylib` from above and outputs another dynamic library named `libalgorithm.dylib`, to be used in the project below.
3. Finally, project "CLI" has one cpp file source file and uses `libalgorithm.dylib` created above. It creates the executable `cli`.

(I created this structure because I plan on using parts of the code base in different applications in the future. In my mind, this structure keeps things modular and clean.)

I am able to compile/build everything and run the executable with a 0 return code. However, there is a computational error in the output triggered by running `cli` against certain data. I suspect the error is in `dataclasses.cpp`. So my plan was to open the file `dataclasses.cpp` in project CLI and mark a breakpoint at the right spot, and then run debug in CLI. But when I attempt that, the breakpoint appears as an empty white circle with a diagonal line and a message

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this 
line.
```

Yet this is not true, the line I have chosen is definitely an executable line.

Note that I am able to successfully use breakpoints in the one source file that is used in project CLI.

CLion version: 2022.2
MacOS 12.2.1

**Question**: How can I debug `dataclasses.cpp` while running in project CLI? I would prefer to not add any new files in project Common; I want to keep this as a tightly defined library. Note that before the data reaches the relevant part of `dataclasses.cpp`, it has gone through multiple manipulations in the code within projects Algorithm and CLI. I know that ideally I should write test cases for everything in `dataclasses.cpp`, but I would like to solve this known issue quickly first.

---

A similar question was raised here, [Can I debug libraries (DLLs) directly using CLion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35887090/can-i-debug-libraries-dlls-directly-using-clion), and the answer suggesting creating an executable in the library project, which I'd like to avoid. Plus the post is six years old and I'm hoping things have changed.